# Caching not working

Tags: .htaccess, caching, yslow

I am trying to set caching for eshop www.radiodovrecka.sk

I have added this to htaccess, but the yslow is still not recognizing caching. Do you know where the problem could be?

code:
`<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
</IfModule>`

Thx for any advices

Answer (score 0):

Add below to cache your html content.

```
ExpiresByType text/html A31536000
```

Comment: Is mod_expires module installed on your server?

Comment: I am not sure, because this is not my server, I am doing it for a friend. How can I check it?